# Анимация созданная с помощью ActionScript в Animate не сохраняется в анимированный gif

Tags: flash, actionscript, animate, gif, swf

Также еще, при сохранении в swf(в этом формате анимация есть) не конвертируется в gif, пишет что файл поврежден. Но он не поврежден же. Честно сказать я не знаю какую информацию еще можно предоставить для уточнения вопроса. Могу например выслать файл swf. Там абсолютно простой код, анимация текста и анимация формы. Мне желательно узнать проблему, чтобы при доработке анимации уже самому справится и сохранить в анимированный gif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагаю, что анимация actionScript не сохраняется в gif. Для gif нужно делать покадровую анимацию, а actionScript используется в основном для интерактивных приложений.